# Python automation: How to assert if string is lower or upper case?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm VERY new to automation, fair warning.
I have an automation script to verify that the canonical tag of a page is present. I also need to assert that it's all lower case. Would I just create an assert after "driver.find_element..." to assert islower() ?

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import unittest


class homepage_canonical(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    global driver
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("websiteurlhere")


def test_hpcanonical(self):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("link[href='canonicalurlhere'][rel='canonical']")



def tearDown(self):
    driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `assertTrue` :

```python
def test_hpcanonical(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("link[href='canonicalurlhere'][rel='canonical']")
    self.assertTrue(element.text.islower())
```